# Get all HTTP traffic with a proxy

Tags: proxy, cisco-asa

I’d like to setup a proxy server that get all HTTP traffic on my network. I think to use Squid installed on Debian.

Below the network diagram:

[image]

I don’t want to setup a proxy server on my LAN because I can’t configure a proy server on each computers.

Can someone tell me what’s the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to setup squid in transparent mode, but your network diagram would change. As the proxy server would NAT, that would replace your cisco as a router too. (and while at it, why not remove your ISP router to not double NAT ?? as if someday you want to create some VPN, you can't in double-NAT)

See a tutorial there; http://xmodulo.com/squid-transparent-web-proxy-centos-rhel.html

There a bit of detail from the tutorial that show how he did it;

> Squid Installation
>
> To set up a transparent proxy with Squid, we start by adding necessary
>   iptables rules. These rules should help you get started, but please
>   make sure that they do not conflict with any of the existing
>   configuration.
>   **iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
>
>   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT--to-port 3128**
>
> The first rule will cause all outbound packets from eth1 (WAN
>   interface) to have the source IP address of eth1 (i.e., enable NAT).
>   The second rule will redirect all incoming HTTP packets (destined to
>   TCP 80) from eth0 (LAN interface) to Squid listening ort (TCP 3128),
>   instead of forwarding it out to WAN interface right away.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there are side-effects of intercepting connections with http, and in fact in our tech support for our product ([WinGate](http://www.wingate.com)) although we support intercepting connections, we recommend against doing it.

1. If you're using authentication at the proxy, the client doesn't know it's talking to a proxy.  If a proxy wants to authenticate an intercepted client, it can only send back a 401 response (not a 407) and this looks to the client like the end server is requesting auth.  for a page with resources from many servers, you may get multiple login dialogs popping up.
2. Caching behaves differently.  There are proxy-specific caching directives that don't work when you are intercepting the connection to the proxy.
3. Some exploits.  In your proposed scenario, where you are diverting the connection from the ASA to the proxy, the destination is rewritten by the ASA, and the connection terminates at the proxy.  The proxy then only has the host header to use as the basis on which to make an upstream connection.  This requires an additional DNS lookup by the proxy, which may result in a different answer than the one the client got when it looked up the site. Also in some cases it's been known for clients to connect to a permitted IP, using a hosts header for a banned site.  The permitted IP gets past the firewall, but the proxy looks up the host header and connects to the different (banned) IP.

You will probably also want to consider what to do about https.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.